# Selenium python not selecting all information

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, load, findelement

I'm working with a table that is way too big:

[image]

It has about 30 cols and it is inside a div (with horizontal scroll).

I'm trying to retrieve the information by doing:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//thead/tr/th[%s]' % i).text
```

However it is returning only part of the information like this:

```
['27/3/04', '26/6/04', '25/9/04', '25/12/04', '26/3/05', '25/6/05', '24/9/05', '31/12/05', '1/4/06', '1/7/06', '', '', '', '', ...]
```

From a certain point it won't return information. I thought that maybe I should wait until the rest of the elements load with:

`WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//thead/tr/th[%s]' % i))).text`

However it shows an error message that is not displayed with the other method. In fact, the error message only displays 'Message'.

Further info:

When I look for the elements that are not returned in the section 'inspect element filter', it does show up:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to share page url ?

Comment: I'd rather not to :s
It is a very simple table tho. It has the following structure (plus some styling+class):
<thead>
   <tr>
       <th>
</></></>
<tbody>
   <tr>
       <td>
</></></>
The thing is that it has its own scrollbar. What I'm trying now is to focus on the inner element and only scroll that in order to make the html load, but I don't really know how to do that.